# How to simplify the unit tests execution in c# when shell is used instead Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, msbuild, xunit

In other languages, running the unit tests is very simple:

**java**

```
mvn test
```

**nodejs**

```
npm run test
```

**python**

```
python -m unittest
```

Also these frameworks give us the chance to configure complex parameters using config files, programming, etc. Also I can add the html report generation in the same command. This is useful for devops automation.

I'm trying to do the same thing in c#, but I haven't succeeded

This shell line works after a lot of research:

```
dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover /p:ExcludeByFile=\"$(pwd)/src/Common/**/*,$(pwd)/src/Startup.cs,$(pwd)/src/Program.cs\" /p:CoverletOutput=$(pwd)/.coverage/
```

After that I need to install an external tool (which requires a payment)

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool
```

And then run another sentence to generate the html report:

```
reportgenerator "-reports:.coverage/coverage.opencover.xml" "-targetdir:.coverage" -reporttypes:Html
```

Due to I need to add more and more configurations (coverage threshold, badge generation, etc), my question is:

> How to simplify the unit tests execution in c# when shell is used?

### Unsuccessful attempts

- **.runsettings**

  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/customizing-code-coverage-analysis?view=vs-2022
  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2022#codecoverage-data-collector
- **CodeCoverage.runsettings**

  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/customizing-code-coverage-analysis?view=vs-2022
- Msbuild targets & tasks

  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-configure-targets-and-tasks?view=vs-2022

Thanks

Comment: The dotnet tool installation has to be done only once, if you do it globally. If you omit the global switch, you should create a tool manifest and save the information there.

Comment: _"Also I can add the html report generation in the same command. This is useful for devops automation."_ - TBH my assumption was that json is better suited for devops automation than html.

Comment: #GuruStron Usually the code coverage shows colors, branches, and numbers using a report published in Jenkins, Travis, SonarQube, CircleCi or attached to the mail. https://camo.githubusercontent.com/b347864035001e4cb56e1d9c795aef2f21b6c57077294cbc87c654f46395905b/68747470733a2f2f64616e69656c70616c6d652e6769746875622e696f2f5265706f727447656e657261746f722f7265736f75726365732f73637265656e73686f74322e77656270

Comment: #Marco, yes you are right and I know it. But for coverage, netcore requires another tool called **reportgenerator**