# How to create a custom task only for unit testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, msbuild

Currently, unit tests in c# needs a lot of shell parameters: [How to simplify the unit tests execution in c# when shell is used instead Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76258066/how-to-simplify-the-unit-tests-execution-in-c-sharp-when-shell-is-used-instead-v)

That's why I'm trying to create a custom task to be able to run the tests and code coverage with **one line** and also keep it cross-platform for windows developers.

I tried something like `dotnet foo` but I could not find any official or workaround.

## dotnet + msbuild

The following task works

```
<Target Name="Foo">
  <Message Text="This is a Foo task" />
</Target>

dotnet msbuild -target:Foo
```

But the problem is: This command loads the main **./src/Main.csproj**, not the **./test/Test.csproj** of tests, so the custom task (for unit test) should be in the **Main.csproj**, which doesn't make sense

```
./src
./src/Controllers
./src/Controllers/**
./src/Main.csproj
./src/Startup.cs
./test
./test/Controllers
./test/Controllers/**
./test/Test.csproj
```

I tried to pass the relative location of **./test/Test.csproj** with

- `--project` without success

But another error is raised: `error MSB1001: Unknown switch.`

So my question is:

> How to create a custom task only for unit testing?

Comment: There is no `--project` switch for MSBuild. See [MSBuild command-line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2022). Also see [dotnet command reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet). You can run the Foo target of your test project with the command `dotnet msbuild -target:Foo ./test/Test.csproj`. You can run all your test projects with the command `dotnet test` in the folder that contains the solution file.

Comment: I tried that option. I will try again. Thanks!

Comment: Hi #JonathanDodds. It worked. Could you convert your comment into an answer? I reviewed both links and there is not any mention of  .csproj files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `--project` switch for MSBuild. See [MSBuild command-line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2022). Also see [dotnet command reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet).

You can run the Foo target of your test project with the following command:

```xml
dotnet msbuild -target:Foo ./test/Test.csproj
```

You can run all your test projects with the following command in the folder that contains the solution file:

```xml
dotnet test
```

Comment: Thanks. The `--project` was taken from https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/3322836/239643139-1c2135e6-2049-471e-88ff-cc3c78fa9937.png and also I had tried putting the ..csproj at the beginning not at the end